# Bending neck down very often

Tags: word-usage, word-request

If someone has a habit of bending his  neck down all the time then what can we call this? Is there any general name for this type of habit?

Comment: Something like *text neck.*

Comment: But isn't it used when someone texts?

Comment: Yes but perhaps the habit is related in some way.

Comment: But if someones walks  with Bending neck down. Then what shuld we call this?

Comment: You mean like someone who's *hunched over*?  Someone who *has poor posture*?

Comment: @snailboat  exactly. I got it :D

Comment: Okay, I'll just convert my comment into an answer, then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're talking about someone who's [**hunched over**](https://www.google.com/search?q=hunched+over&tbm=isch).

We can say someone who's constantly hunching over has [**poor posture**](https://www.google.com/search?q=poor+posture&tbm=isch), although there are other ways posture can be bad, too.

(The links go to Google Image Search so you can see what sorts of postures are associated with each phrase.)

Answer (score 2):

In general, it may be called a [mannerism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mannerism).

> 1. a habitual or characteristic manner, mode, or way of doing something; distinctive quality or style, as in behavior or speech:
>      "He has an annoying mannerism of tapping his fingers while he talks."

If there is a medical jargon/terminology for this, I am honestly not aware; but in general, such may be called a mannerism.